# Change Date format directly in the adapter Android

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, android-adapter

I'm building an app that retrieves data from an API, the problem is the Date format that is coming from the API is "YYYY-MM-DD", and I need to pass it in this format: "DD/MM/YYYY"

How can I format it directly in my adapter?

```
ViagemModel mViagemModel = new ViagemModel();
mViagemModel = viagens.get(position);



holder.Saida.setText(mViagemModel.getDate_saida());
holder.Chegada.setText(mViagemModel.getDate_chegada());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

An Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse("2014-09-13"); //YOUR DATE HERE
df.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String newDate = df.format(date);  //Output: newDate = "13/09/2014"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where should I put this snippet of code? The date is coming from the API and I need to change its format in the adapter to show it in the new format, I'm very new to android development.

Comment: You can change the date before setting it into the text view. i.e. before the `setText` method.